# Remove last 3 letters of string in Django template [:-3]

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm doing the following:

```
{% for wrapping in wrappings %}  //array of strings
<input type="radio" value="{{ wrapping[:-3] }}" etc
```

I want to output all the string in wrapping minus the last 3 letters but am recieving a:

`TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[:-3]' from 'wrapping[:-3]`.

Any idea what's wrong/how to do this please?  Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just use the slice filter:

```
{{ wrapping|slice:":-3" }}
```

Comment: Because it's Django's templating engine - which imposes certain syntax constraints on tags and you can't treat it exactly as Python - in fact, it's designed to make sure you don't... It's worth looking at most of the builtin filters though....

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter for that.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ variable|slice:":-3" }}` would do it.